# Does phpredis support redis 3?

Tags: redis, phpredis

I have been searching for this information. I have used phpredis with redis server 2.x, now due to server migration we have redis server 3.x. Does phpredis support redis 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it support Redis 3.0.x. And in present time (winter 2016):

- does not support redis cluster.
- does not support Redis 3.2.x new commands like GEO family.